# How to pass in command line values for a gherkin step

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, python-behave

I have a test that is being kicked off via Jenkins, that has the following information:

branch=def

jenkinsProject=abc123

build=123

Considering that these values will change with every build, using an examples table would not be ideal, nor work?

**How can I use these values that I get from jenkins to pass them into my gherkin step?**

```
Given I pass in the following data "<ARGS.dynamic.jenkinsProject>" "<ARGS.dynamic.branch>" and "<ARGS.dynamic.build>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Feature files should be considered static, readable specifications.  It's generally not advisable to create them on the fly with variables, because that somewhat misses the point of BDD.

If you really need to read variables within your steps, I'd recommend using environment variables and reading them in your step definition with `os.environ.get(...)`

That way your step can read `Given I read the branch from our environment` and the definition will read `JENKINS_BRANCH` or whatnot that you set within the Jenkins environment.